# Confused about how Loop 2 is defined

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-theory, mesh-analysis

In one of my exercises, I am presented with the following circuit:

[image: Circuit]

We are asked first to write some loop equations for the circuit. Naturally, they are given to be defined as:

[image: Loop Equations]

What I cannot understand is how Equation 1.2 is defined. If Ud1, which corresponds to the node connected to the op-amp is set to 0, then how can it be said that it's suddenly equal to -Uo? This equation makes sense if Ud1 = -Uo but given that the equation is set as Ud1 = 0, I can't understand it.

Here is some further information about the question:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The potential at the positve terminal of A1 is Uo so you can see the equation is correct. 
Or you can consider the loop fro Ui, Z1, positive terminal of A1, negative terminal of A1, Uo, ground and write KVL for that loop.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply! I agree that 1.2 is correct, but how would that come about from the premise that Ud1=0?

Comment: @nyquil43 Maybe they meant to say Ud1=Uo but whomever was translating the notes to the problem turned Uo into o and that into zero?

Comment: That actually makes so much sense. Thanks so much!